# Ударение в слове "амигдала"

Tags: орфоэпия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существуют ли какие-либо авторитетные источники, в которых было бы указано, на какой слог падает ударение в слове **"амигдала"**?

В не очень надежных интернет-источниках я нашел несколько отличающихся друг от друга вариантов (включая совсем уж экзотическую версию с ударением на первое "а"). Причина этого видимо в том, что с одной стороны, в английском языке слово amygdala имеет ударение на 'и' (*[əˈmɪgdələ]*), а с другой, ранее вошедшая в русский язык форма мужского рода "амигдал" (миндаль) имеет ударение на третий слог: амигда́л.

Так как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю я ни греческого языка, ни латыни, но путем долгих поисков обнаружилась следующая информация (думаю, в источниках, заслуживающих доверие).

Л. Г. Чернявская, "Латинский язык" ([стр. 20—21](https://elib.vsmu.by/bitstream/123/189/1/Cherniavskaia-LG_Latinskij%20iazyk_2011.pdf)):

В словах, состоящих из трех и более слогов, ударение падает на второй слог от конца слова, если гласный в этом слоге долгий. Ударение падает на третий слог от конца слова, если гласный во втором слоге от конца слова — краткий. Нужно помнить правила долготы и краткости гласного в предпоследнем слоге слова, состоящего их трёх и более слогов.

**Nota bene!** Слог, за которым следует один согласный, может быть и долгим, и кратким. В этом случае долгота или краткость гласного предпоследнего слога определяется при помощи словаря, где долгота гласного условно обозначается надстрочным знаком (ā), а краткость — (ă).

Т. Г. Шавырина, "Латынь. Учебник для ветеринаров" ([Ударение в сложных однословных терминах](https://studfile.net/preview/6216195/page:30/)):

В русском языке латинские термины греческого происхождения сохраняют исконное ударение, например: ветерина́рия — veterinа́ria; ме́тод — mе́thodus.

**Amygdăla** (лат.) — миндаль.
Считается, что слово *amygdala* пришло в латынь из древнегреческого языка (*ἀμυγδάλη*), и уже потом оно было заимствовано рядом европейских языков.
В нашем слове предпоследний слог краткий, поэтому предполагаю, что ударение все-таки нужно ставить на "и": **ами́гдала**.